# Selecting rows with a value of False

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set and during validation I have marked the "rejected" rows by masking the bad cell with the boolean False. 
I am looking to split that dataframe into two, the good and the bad data. The following code works perfectly for grabbing the good data from the data frame. It selects the rows where that do not contain the boolean False.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"A":[1, 2, 3], "B":[4, False, 6], "C":[7, 8, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

for col in df.columns:
    df = df.loc[df[col] != False]
print(df)
```

However, now I want to select the rows that do have the value of False. However if I change the line below, it returns nothing?

```
df = df.loc[df[col] == False]
```

My two questions are:

1. Why does this not work?
2. How could I accomplish this task since the above does not work?

Comment: Without all of the code, I can't say—but if you've already made `df` the entries without `False`, then trying to find `False` in `df` later won't work. Maybe give each different names.

Comment: `df[df.eq(False).any(1)]`

Comment: @QuangHoang That worked.  The problem should be perfect reproducible with the given code above, is it not? It's perfectly reasonable to mask the data with another value however.

Comment: The problem is `0==False` is `True`. So if your data contains `0`, the code will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer per @QuangHoang.

Replacing the for-loop with the below:
df[df.eq(False).any(1)]

Reason:
0==False is True